# How to safely refreeze cooked beans?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, freezing, beans

I have cooked a kilo of black eye beans and made a meal with half of them. I intend to freeze the rest (the other half) to make another meal next week and freeze them for later meals. This last step means that the frozen beans are going to be cooked and refreeze them again.

Is this procedure a safe one to take? I regularly cook full meals and freeze them in portions for later meals but not from already frozen ones.

Answer (score 0):

**Sure.**

I have done this dozens of times.  Beans are durable and super forgiving.  They might get a little mushy but that is fine for black beans.

For other kinds of food the risk is that the might get overcooked the second time and lose character you want.